# MyBatis Mapper Xml Stored Proc Call: Supply Default Parameter Value

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-mybatis

I need to be able to pass default parameters to a MyBatis xml mapper.  Originally, this is what I was doing:

```
<select     id="someFunction"
            parameterType="com.myCompany.Member"
            resultMap="memberMap"
            statementType="CALLABLE" >
            {call dbo.trp_MembersGet_ById_sp  (#{memberId,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN}, 1)}
</select>
```

The default parameter in this case would be the second param, '1'.  This seemed to work, but all traces in the database make this a BATCH call.  I need them to be RPC.  Passing an additional parameter fixes this:

```
<select id="someFunction"
                parameterType="com.myCompany.Member"
                resultMap="memberMap"
                statementType="CALLABLE" >
                {call dbo.trp_MembersGet_ById_sp  (#{memberId,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN}, 
{secondParam,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN})}
</select>
```

...but I'd rather have it be a default param so I don't have to have my model have this additional field.

So, ideally, I think I'd like something like this (below does not work):

```
<select     id="someFunction"
            parameterType="com.myCompany.Member"
            resultMap="memberMap"
            statementType="CALLABLE" >
            {call dbo.trp_MembersGet_ById_sp  (#{memberId,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN}, {1,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN})}
</select>
```

Where '1' is the default value.  Is there any way to do this?